# Start multiple new window but keep the current view alive

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have an employee session bean which has a list of related employee beans of the same class.  My users need to be able to be viewing the "main" employee and from that employee spawn multiple browser windows to display the related employee's information but keep the "main" or "root" employee view alive so they can continue to work from there.

What I believe is currently happening is JSF will open a new window and render the related employee but then loses track of the original window/view so if you click on a command link or run anything from the original window (after you have spawned the new window using the target attribute in the command link) the second action will not run or call any methods in the session bean it doesn't seem to do anything except for reload the page.  I believe because you are trying to run an action from an old JSF view that is no longer registered so when the framework receives a request from this stale view it has to register? maybe?

Essentially I am trying to have multiple displays of the same session bean type active for the same user and have each session bean view attached to separate browser windows.

Please let me know if you have any ideas. or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Please be more specific in describing the concrete problem. Elaborate in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. For example, what exactly happens when you said *" if you try to run a command from the original window it ignores it"*.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for the constructive criticism.  I will edit and add some more info.

Comment: I think what you are looking for in few words is how to keep one view alive while the user is working in other without get ViewExpiredException. Both Mojarra (number of logical views) and MyFaces (MYFACES-3117 see org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_SEQUENTIAL_VIEWS_IN_SESSION web config param) has some workarounds for this problem that are good enough, but the final solution could be on JSF 2.2.

Comment: How your application is behaving depends a lot on the components you're using for navigation (i.e., `h:link` or `h:commandLink`) and the scope of your backing beans (request, session, etc.). Seeing some of the XHTML and Java sources is required for anyone to understand why you're seeing this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer.

I solved this problem by calling a request bean method using a command link (and opening it in a new window).  This allowed me to have multiple broswer windows open (each a new call to a request bean) without effecting my session bean "main" employee bean.  The users could then view multiple employees at once in multiple windows.  Part of my problem was related to a misunderstanding of JSF.  I can only have one "employee" session bean in the session at once so when I was trying to spawn multiple browswer windows with different employees they were all referencing the same session employee bean which won't work.  JSF would attach to the new window that was opened and no longer be aware of the original opening window.

Anyway to do something like this I would suggest request beans that was a new one is instantiated each time you open a new window to view a new employee.

Sorry because of policy I cannot post any code

Comment: Yes, using a `@SessionScoped` bean for data that may be different in different windows is a classic mistake. I have also made that mistake :-/. Note that request-scoped beans are not the only alternative; often view-scope makes more sense (or even a custom scope).